# What is the input pattern for org.sql.Date

Tags: sql, hibernate, date

On a Website, i want a field that gets a Date as Input and then save that date in a "Attendee"-Class.

```
public class Teilnehmer {


    private Date jahrgang = null;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy="increment")
    @Column (name="ID")

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   

    @Column (name="Jahrgang")
    public Date getJahrgang() {
        return jahrgang;
    }
    public void setJahrgang(Date jahrgang) {
        this.jahrgang = jahrgang;
    }
```

That attribute 'jahrgang' has the Type org.sql.Date. Now, it doesn't matter what i put into that text field, when i send the form, it reloads the page and returns the already filled field and marks the Date-field red. It looks kinda like this:
[image: The Returned form]

What is the input type in this case?

**EDIT:**

I don't get any unusual Log outputs when i send the form.

part of the form where i input:

```
<p:outputLabel for="eintritt" value="Eintritt: "/>
<h:inputText name="eintritt" id="eintritt" value="#{AdminAdd.teilnehmer.eintrittsdatum}"></h:inputText>
<p:watermark for="eintritt" value="Eintritt"></p:watermark>
```

Comment: Is there an error in the logs? How do you fill the date in your entity with the date from form?

Comment: The logs don't show anything unusual.

Comment: Date field in the code is called jahrgang, I'm not sure why you input eintritt. But assuming that it's written the same, and that this approach works (I have no experience with direct html to entity translation) I'd give 80% that it's a date formatting issue. You're trying to set a date field with a String after all.